# Strange add-on Saleplus - what is it and how to remove?

Tags: browser-addons, unwanted-application

I use Avira, but it see no trouble. The problem is that I get strange redirects in my Chrome browser. Also I got many ads while browsing after installed this add-on.

Comment: First step would be to delete the Chrome user profile directory to verify the problem is indeed adware and not something else.

Comment: [Remove “Ads by SalePlus” virus (Easy Removal Guide)](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/ads-by-saleplus-removal/)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Saleplus is an adware. And I remember it's rather difficult to remove it. To clean it completely you need:

1. Uninstall from control panel.
2. Delete manifest.json file of the extension using developers mode in Chrome.
3. Delete registry keys containing saleplus using regedit.
4. After that remove it from browser extensions.
   I found a [really working guides here](http://pcfixhelp.net/ads/763-how-to-remove-saleplus). The best thing is that there is a video-guide on the site - I mainly used it.

Comment: Can someone explain to me why this is getting downvoted, as the link is actually very relevant and pretty helpful